# Highlighting selected node in d3 js

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am working on angular app and d3 js.m I am using d3 org tree in my applicationb. My code is as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-org-chart@2"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-flextree@2.1.2/build/d3-flextree.js"></script>

    <div class="chart-container" style="height: 1200px"></div>

    <link
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script>
      var chart;
      d3.csv(
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bumbeishvili/sample-data/main/org.csv'
      ).then((dataFlattened) => {
        dataFlattened.forEach((d) => {
          const val = Math.round(d.name.length / 2);
          d.progress = [...new Array(val)].map((d) => Math.random() * 25 + 5);
        });
        chart = new d3.OrgChart()
          .container('.chart-container')
          .svgHeight(window.innerHeight - 10)
          .data(dataFlattened)
          .nodeHeight((d) => 170)
          .nodeWidth((d) => {
            if (d.depth == 0) return 500;
            return 330;
          })
          .childrenMargin((d) => 90)
          .compactMarginBetween((d) => 65)
          .compactMarginPair((d) => 100)
          .neightbourMargin((a, b) => 50)
          .siblingsMargin((d) => 100)
          .buttonContent(({ node, state }) => {
            return `<div style="color:#2CAAE5;border-radius:5px;padding:3px;font-size:10px;margin:auto auto;background-color:#040910;border: 1px solid #2CAAE5"> <span style="font-size:9px">${
              node.children
                ? `<i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>`
                : `<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>`
            }</span> ${node.data._directSubordinates}  </div>`;
          })
          .linkUpdate(function (d, i, arr) {
            d3.select(this)
              .attr('stroke', (d) =>
                d.data._upToTheRootHighlighted ? '#14760D' : '#2CAAE5'
              )
              .attr('stroke-width', (d) =>
                d.data._upToTheRootHighlighted ? 15 : 1
              );

            if (d.data._upToTheRootHighlighted) {
              d3.select(this).raise();
            }
          })
          .nodeContent(function (d, i, arr, state) {
            const svgStr = `<svg width=150 height=75  style="background-color:none"> <path d="M 0,15 L15,0 L135,0 L150,15 L150,60 L135,75 L15,75 L0,60" fill="#2599DD" stroke="#2599DD"/> </svg>`;
            return `
                          <div class="left-top" style="position:absolute;left:-10px;top:-10px">  ${svgStr}</div>
                          <div class="right-top" style="position:absolute;right:-10px;top:-10px">  ${svgStr}</div>
                          <div class="right-bottom" style="position:absolute;right:-10px;bottom:-14px">  ${svgStr}</div>
                          <div class="left-bottom" style="position:absolute;left:-10px;bottom:-14px">  ${svgStr}</div>
                          <div style="font-family: 'Inter'; background-color:#040910;sans-serif; position:absolute;margin-top:-1px; margin-left:-1px;width:${
                            d.width
                          }px;height:${d.height}px;border-radius:0px;border: 2px solid #2CAAE5">
                             
                             <div class="pie-chart-wrapper" style="margin-left:-10px;margin-top:5px;width:320px;height:300px"></div>
                           
                            <div style="color:#2CAAE5;position:absolute;right:15px;top:-20px;">
                              <div style="font-size:15px;color:#2CAAE5;margin-top:32px"> ${
                                d.data.name
                              } </div>
                              <div style="font-size:10px;"> ${
                                d.data.positionName || ''
                              } </div>
                              <div style="font-size:10px;"> ${
                                d.data.id || ''
                              } </div>
                              ${
                                d.depth == 0
                                  ? `                              <br/>
                              <div style="max-width:200px;font-size:10px;">
                                A corporate history of Ian is a chronological account of a business or other co-operative organization he founded.  <br><br>Usually it is produced in written format but it can also be done in audio or audiovisually  
                              </div>`
                                  : ''
                              }

                            </div>

                            <div style="position:absolute;left:-5px;bottom:10px;">
                              <div style="font-size:10px;color:#2CAAE5;margin-left:20px;margin-top:32px"> Progress </div>
                              <div style="color:#2CAAE5;margin-left:20px;margin-top:3px;font-size:10px;"> 
                                <svg width=150 height=30> ${d.data.progress
                                  .map((h, i) => {
                                    return `<rect  width=10 x="${
                                      i * 12
                                    }" height=${h}  y=${
                                      30 - h
                                    } fill="#B41425"/>`;
                                  })
                                  .join('')}  </svg>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          
  `;
          })
          .nodeUpdate(function (d, i, arr) {
            d3.select(this)
              .select('.node-rect')
              .attr('stroke', (d) =>
                d.data._highlighted || d.data._upToTheRootHighlighted
                  ? '#14760D'
                  : 'none'
              )
              .attr(
                'stroke-width',
                d.data._highlighted || d.data._upToTheRootHighlighted ? 40 : 1
              );

            const pieChartWrapperNode = d3
              .select(this)
              .select('.pie-chart-wrapper')
              .node();
            const val = (d.data.name.length * 5) % 100; // Dummy calc
            // General pie chart invokation code
            new PieChart()
              .data([
                { key: 'plan', color: '#6EC2EA', value: val },
                { key: 'exec', color: '#0D5AAF', value: 100 - val },
              ])
              .container(pieChartWrapperNode)
              .svgHeight(200)
              .svgWidth(320)
              .marginTop(40)
              .image(d.data.imageUrl)
              .backCircleColor('#1F72A7')
              .defaultFont('Inter')
              .render();
          })
          .render();

        const url = `data:image/png;base64,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`;
        const replaced = url.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm);
        d3.select('.svg-chart-container')
          .style(
            'background',
            'radial-gradient(circle at center, #04192B 0, #000B0E 100%) url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bumbeishvili/coronavirus.davidb.dev/master/glow.png")'
          )
          .style(
            'background-image',
            `url(${replaced}), radial-gradient(circle at center, #04192B 0, #000B0E 100%)`
          );
      });

      function downloadPdf() {
        chart.exportImg({
          save: false,
          onLoad: (base64) => {
            var pdf = new jspdf.jsPDF();
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = base64;
            img.onload = function () {
              pdf.addImage(
                img,
                'JPEG',
                5,
                5,
                595 / 3,
                ((img.height / img.width) * 595) / 3
              );
              pdf.save('chart.pdf');
            };
          },
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="./pieChart.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.3.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: #000c0e;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      var index = 0;
      var compact = 0;
      var actNdCent = 0;
    </script>

    <style>
      .btn {
        margin: 3px;
        color: inherit;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        white-space: normal;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 0.125rem;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 16%),
          0 2px 10px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 16%), 0 2px 10px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
        -webkit-transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out,
          background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out,
          -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
        transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out,
          border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
        transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out,
          border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
        transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out,
          border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out,
          -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
        padding: 0.84rem 2.14rem;
        font-size: 0.81rem;
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #212529;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
        font-size: 1rem;
        line-height: 1.5;
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
      }

      .btn-action-button {
        text-transform: lowercase;
        font-size: 11px !important;
        border-radius: 7px !important;
        color: white !important;
        padding: 4px 5px !important;
        background-color: #1d2643 !important;
      }

      .action-buttons {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 35px;
      }

      .svg-chart-container:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #04192b 0, #000b0e 100%);
      }
    </style>

    <div class="action-buttons">
      <button
        onclick='chart.setExpanded("O-6164").render()'
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i> Expand
      </button>
      <br />

      <button
        onclick='chart.setExpanded("O-6164",false).render()'
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i> Collapse</button
      ><br />

      <button
        onclick='chart.addNode({imageUrl:"https:\/\/raw.githubusercontent.com/bumbeishvili/Assets/master/Projects/D3/Organization%20Chart/cto.jpg",id:"root child",parentId:"O-6066",name:"test",progress:[25,20,15,10]})'
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-folder-plus"></i> Add Node
      </button>
      <br />

      <button
        onclick='chart.removeNode("O-6067")'
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-user-times"></i> remove</button
      ><br />

      <button
        onclick="chart.fit()"
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-sync"></i> fit
      </button>
      <br />

      <button
        onclick='chart.layout(["right","bottom","left","top"][index++%4]).render().fit()'
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-retweet"></i> swap
      </button>
      <br />

      <button
        onclick="chart.compact(!!(compact++%2)).render().fit()"
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-sitemap"></i> compact
      </button>
      <br />

      <button
        onclick="chart.setActiveNodeCentered(!!(actNdCent++%2)).render()"
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-border-none"></i> center Active
      </button>
      <br />

      <button
        onclick='chart.setCentered("O-6162").render()'
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-compress-arrows-alt"></i> center
      </button>
      <br />
      <button
        onclick='chart.setHighlighted("O-6162").render()'
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-highlighter"></i> mark</button
      ><br />
      <button
        onclick='chart.setUpToTheRootHighlighted("O-6162").render().fit()'
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-route"></i> mark root
      </button>
      <br />
      <button
        onclick="chart.clearHighlighting()"
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i> clear mark
      </button>
      <br />
      <button
        onclick="chart.fullscreen('body')"
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-expand"></i> fullscreen</button
      ><br />

      <button
        onclick="chart.exportImg()"
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="far fa-images"></i> export img
      </button>
      <br />

      <button
        onclick="chart.exportImg({full:true})"
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="far fa-images"></i> export full img
      </button>
      <br />

      <button
        onclick="chart.exportSvg()"
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-file-download"></i> export svg
      </button>
      <br />
      <button
        onclick="chart.expandAll()"
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-angle-double-down"></i> expand all</button
      ><br />

      <button
        onclick="chart.collapseAll()"
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-angle-double-up"></i> collapse all</button
      ><br />

      <button
        onclick="downloadPdf()"
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i> export pdf
      </button>
      <br />

      <button
        onclick='chart.connections([{from:"O-6069",to:"O-6070",label:"Conflicts of interest"}]).render()'
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i> add link
      </button>
      <br />

      <button
        onclick="chart.zoomOut()"
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-minus"></i> zoom out</button
      ><br />
      <button
        onclick="chart.zoomIn()"
        class="btn btn-action-button waves-effect waves-light"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> zoom in
      </button>
      <br />
    </div>

    <a
      target="_blank"
      href="https://github.com/bumbeishvili/d3-organization-chart"
    >
      <img
        style="position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0; z-index: 2"
        width="149"
        height="149"
        src="https://bumbeishvili.github.io/d3-tooltip/forkme.png"
        alt="Fork me on GitHub"
      />
    </a>

    <script src="https://storage.ko-fi.com/cdn/scripts/overlay-widget.js"></script>
    <script>
      kofiWidgetOverlay.draw('bumbeishvili', {
        type: 'floating-chat',
        'floating-chat.donateButton.text': 'Tip Us',
        'floating-chat.donateButton.background-color': '#00b9fe',
        'floating-chat.donateButton.text-color': '#fff',
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Stackblitz is as follows-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-o5t1ha

I just want to highlight node which is clicked with green border and green background and all other remaining node with pink border and no background color. How can I do that?

Comment: Code seems to miss the best practice for Angular applications.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could try to really integrate Angular and D3 the right way.
What you're doing here will quickly be unmaintanable, and hard to debug.

There are resources here and there about how to integrate both :

https://medium.com/swlh/reactive-charts-in-angular-8-using-d3-4550bb0b4255

When you're done, things will eventually look cleaner I think.
Cheers.